# Openbox: How to ignore keybinding based on condition?

Tags: openbox

Using Openbox I'm looking for a way to pass through a keybinding as normal if a condition is not met.

I was looking unsuccessfully for something like "default", "cancel" or "ignore" in the documentation for [bindings](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) and [actions](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions).

As an example, let's say I want to disable ctrl-p – but only inside Firefox.

```
<keybind key="C-p">
  <action name="If">
    <query>
      <title>*Firefox*</title>
    </query>
    <then>
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>notify-send "Firefox is active. Ignoring."</command>
      </action>
    </then>
    <else>
      <!-- What might go here to pass through ctrl-p as normal? -->
    </else>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Unfortunately, if the window is *not* Firefox, then nothing happens. The ctrl-p is effectively canceled.

Is there a way I can pass through the ctrl-p so it can be handled as normal by
all other applications?

(Please note I'd prefer a solution inside Openbox. xdotool or similar is not reliable and only a last resort.)